# Comparing sampling distributions

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

We have two independent observations $X_1$ and $X_2$ both from a poission distribution with $$X_1 \sim Pois(a\lambda) \\ X_2 \sim Pois(b\lambda)$$ with $a$ and $b$ known and positive.

We calculate the MLE and find that $\lambda = \frac{2n}{a\sum_{i=1}^nx_1+b\sum_{i=1}^nx_2}$

Calculated by the following:

$$L(a\lambda, b\lambda;x) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;a\lambda,b\lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}ab\lambda^2e^{-\lambda(ax_1+bx_2)} $$ By taking the logarithm and calculating the first derivative with respect to $\lambda$ and setting everything to zero, we get the following: $$ \hat{\lambda} = \frac{2n}{a\sum_{i=1}^nx_{1i}+b\sum_{i=1}^nx_{2i}}$$

$$\text{For }n=2,\hat{\lambda}=\frac{2}{ax_1+bx_2}$$

Now, the question wants me to compare the estimator of lambda to the following sampling distribution estimators:

$$T_1 = \frac{X_1-X_2}{a-b}\\ T_2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{X_1}{a}+\frac{X_2}{b} \right)$$

To recommend an estimator for $\lambda$.

By taking the variance:

$$Var(T_1)=\frac{1}{(b-a)^2}\left(Var(X_1)-Var(X_2) \right) = \frac{1}{(b-a)^2}(\lambda-\lambda)=0 \\ Var(T_2) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a^2}Var(X_1)+\frac{1}{b^2}Var(X_2)\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\lambda}{a^2}+\frac{\lambda}{b^2}\right)$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Where are we given n independent observations of both X_1 and X_2? We only have two observations, therefore the summation in the MLE estimator does not make sense. Once we find the estimators, we can compare the efficiency of the T1 and T2 with MLE estimator. You can compute the MSE of each estimator.

Comment: @NisargJain It's been some while since I have worked with estimators. I have updated my post with the variance. The MSE is the same as variance, and we know that Var(X) = $\lambda$. So the best estimator is $T_1$ because its MSE is 0?

Comment: the variance of first estimator is not 0. $Var(X_1-X_2) = Var(X_1) +(-1)^2Var(X_2) = Var(X_1)+Var(X_2) = a \lambda + b \lambda$. Also MSE(T)= Var(T) + Bias(T)^2.